# Is there any workaround in c++ to mock / derive from final class

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am using pistache framework for my C++ REST server and I want to create a google mock for google test. I want to mock `Pistache::Http::ResponseWriter` but this class is marked as final. Is there any workaround to mock/derive final class for testing purposes? Editing the sources is option, but its stinky.

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <pistache/http.h>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void handler(const std::string& example, Pistache::Http::ResponseWriter& response){
        response.send(Pistache::Http::Code::Ok, example);
    }
};

// error: cannot derive from ‘final’ base ‘Pistache::Http::ResponseWriter’ in derived type ‘A’
struct ResponseWriterMock : public Pistache::Http::ResponseWriter {
};
```

Comment: You could use a macro where just when you compile tests you change the declaration of the `ResponseWriter` to not be final. But yes, this means editing the source.

Comment: Make it a member variable of your mock class; clone it's interface (copy/paste from the header) and do a pass-through for all the methods.

Answer (score 0):

the final keyword is used to prevent errors that can happen when deriving from classes that aren't designed to be base classes.  For example, the base class might not have a virtual destructor, and can result in very hard to track bugs.

The library designer intended to stop you from inheriting from this class.